# How can I let my different objects in my ArrayList perform the method each class has (salaris())

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Let's say you have different employees but each employee class has a salary() method. How can I make these different objects I made and put in an ArrayList use the method salary()?

```
public void betaalSalarissen(){
    for(int counter = 0;werknemers.size()>counter;counter++){
        Class objectClass = werknemers.get(counter).getClass();
        **objectClass.salaris();** //this won't work, help please!

    }
}
public void neemInDienst(Object persoon){   //objects from different classes, different employees
    werknemers.add(persoon);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the quick solution here is to cast the result from ``` werknemers.get(counter)``to your ```Employee` class (class name just guessed)

```
((Employee)werknemers.get(counter)).salaris();
```

but in the long run you should apply a generic parameter to the collection variable and the methods parameter:

```
private Collection<Employee>  werknemers = new ArrayList<>();

public void neemInDienst(Employee persoon){   //objects from different classes, different employees
    werknemers.add(persoon);
}
```

then you can simply iterate over the element without cast just as ChiefTwoPencils suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to try to get the class; just use polymorphism.

```
public class Employee {
    public double salaris() { ... }
}
public class CommissionedEmployee extends Employee {
    @Override
    public double salaris() { ... }
}

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
// add some employees of whatever subtype(s)
for (Employee e : employees) {
    e.salaris();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it also worked! I think I just got to understand polymorphism better. Thanks friend.